# Vertical or Horizontal "settings" table?

Tags: php, mysql

Creating a CMS, I have a "settings" table, in which I store many CMS settings. Such as Site name, URL, etc.

I have seen it where each **row** is a setting (Vertical)

I have also seen it where each **column** is a setting (Horizontal)

What do you think the *CORRECT* method is?

Vertical:

```
+----------------------+
+id |   name   | value +
+----------------------+
+0  |   site   | (url) +
+1  | comments |   0   +
+----------------------+
```

Horizontal:

```
+---------------------------------------------+
+id  |  site   |  comments  |  title  |  etc  +
+---------------------------------------------+
+0   |  (url)  |     0      |YourSite |  etc  +
+---------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally would use a vertical way of doing it, as it doesn't restrict you to the settings for which you currently have a column. You can add as many as needed later. With a horizontal approach you'd have to add a new column for each setting.

What Knossos says about caching is true, make sure to cache the settings whenever possible.
Tables like these are read on every pageview and cost database performance while they shouldn't. Memcached is a very good suggestion but if you only have a single webserver, you can use APC just as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would store all settings in one row. That leaves room for additional "sites" should you require in the future (for example, localisation). I would also make sure that I [cached these settings](http://memcached.org/).

Answer (score 0):

My self if your using this for one site only use the vertical as you shown if you think that later the same CMS might be used for multiple sites use the vertical but add a site_id column even if for now it has a default of 1 and all settings use it again though make sure you have some caching system enabled